# Custom row in Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, customization

I just need that items in a Spinner rows wraps when their length is large.
So I did this:

item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAddr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Address"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

layout with Spinner:

...

```
   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spAddr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

...

and a code to implement data

```
Cursor c = tbl.getAddr(id);

    getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[] { "address" };
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c,
            from, to);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner s = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spAddr);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I do not know how to use my row-resource item.xml in here. How can I implement my custom row?

UPD: after I change item.xml with MSquare code.

Closed Spinner

[image: Closed Spinner]

Opened Spinner

[image: Opened Spinner]

And when I choose item I've got picture 1 again.

Comment: create custom adapter along with custom layout for row.

Comment: based on SimpleCursorAdapter? like in ListView?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Your item.xml should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Address"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

and in the code you can use now:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
        R.layout.item, c, from, to);
```

Try it out.

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It shows the text Address when it closed, items are not wrapped as I wanted and when I choose an item the text in spinner doesn't change, it always shows "Address".

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. What do you mean "when it closed"? Also your question didn't mention choosing an item? You have onItemClickListener somewhere? Post the code and try to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: In item.xml, try removing android:text="Address", and add android:singleLine="false" in TextView.

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but maybe it will be helpfull for someone 
This is my code for custom spinner

```
final CardDAO cardDAO = new CardDAO(activity);
final Cursor cursor =  cardDAO.getNameAllActiveCard();

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(activity,
                R.layout.spinner_row,
                cursor, new String[] {"pan", "name"}, new int[] {R.id.spinner_pan, R.id.spinner_name}, 0);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.operCardList);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

spinner_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/spinner_pan"
   android:paddingRight="5dp"
   android:textSize="13sp" />
```

spinner_dropdown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_name"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Now you can customise it as you wish